# How do I post a photo to a Facebook event?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I've been using the PHP SDK to try and post photos to a test user's event on Facebook:

```
$c = 0;
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
while ($c < count($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
 aFile = $_FILES['file'];
 //..other code for ui and validity checks..//
 $real = realpath($aFile["tmp_name"][$c]);
 $attachment = array('message' => 'Test upload');
 $attachment['image'] = '@'.$real; //also tried other keys. Please see below...
 try {
  $result = $facebook->api('/'.$event_id.'/photos?access_token='.$access_token, 'post', $attachment);
 }
 catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  echo('Could not post image to Facebook:'.var_export($e));
 }
 $c++;
}
```

Unfortunately, all I get is errors:

```
'message' => 'An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.', 'type' => 'OAuthException', 'code' => 2
```

I've been trying for two days and this is the only upload code I have so I'm hardly overloading Facebook with (in my case) attempting to send a 500x500 jpg file every so often.

If I alter the `../photos?access_token=…` to `../feed?access_token=..` then the text gets posted but not the image.

I've also tried handling the image with:

```
$attachment[basename($real)] = '@'.$real;
```

and

```
$attachment['source'] = '@'.$real;
```

and

```
$attachment['picture'] = '@'.$real;
```

All with no success for local files. But the last key option on `$attachment` will allow a post with a URL to a picture on a (random) website.

Could someone tell me whether I'm 'post'ing to the correct open graph edge or if there's a mistake in my code for handling the image's data?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was a mixture of test user accounts being corrupted or old and of my file path's.

I deleted the test user and completely recreated new ones and that along with a dummy file placed in a place I knew I could get to worked with the facebook command:

```
$photo_return = $facebook->api($event_id.'/photos', 'POST', array('source' => '@dummy_file.jpg', 'message' => 'Photo post'));
```